# final and memory leak

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, final

As far as I know final tells the CPU that it can caches the variable/object (It anyway differs from CPU to CPU. I think x86 CPU-s are really doing a core cache L1)
My question is:

In the following example I have an object myObjectFinal set as final so the CPU can cache it and then it changes a value inside. Does this mean that myObject is not guaranteed to be also changed?

Does the reference gets broken if I set final and the CPU decide to cache it?

What if I change myObject, is the cached final guaranteed to get also changed?

```
// thread 1
volatile MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
// thread 2
final MyObject myObjectFinal = myObject;
myObjectFinal.setData(1);
// thread 1
myObject.setData(2);
```

Maybe the code does not tell exactly what I mean. So, the main question is: Does making a mutable object final or volatile have any repercussions to how the object is cached by the CPU. If it does then when I should use final or volatile on mutable objects?

Does the CPU ever caches a mutable object or final/volatile have absolutely no effect on them and are used only for coding consistency?

Comment: Your question is more about the `volatile` keyword than about the `final`. Having your (member) variable declared `volatile` the JVM will asure that changes in other threads are visible in the current thread. without `volatile` keyword it will not, regadless of the `final` keyword.

Comment: **I have an object myObjectFinal set as final** - No, you don't have `Object` set as `final` , you have **Object Reference** set as `final`. Generally, `volatile` and `final` make sense for visibility of primitive types and other scenarios require explicit `synchronization`.

Comment: @Sabir It is obviously that I am putting final on the object reference! My question will make no sense if I copy the object or if I use primitives. Your comment does not help at all. And again Synchronization is different than volatile. This question is about caching in CPU not making the part of the code atomic.

Comment: I am sorry that I my comment didn't help you at all, will try to put better comments and I am not the down voter.

Comment: On the other hand I strongly agree with you that volatile or final makes sense only on primitives and immutable objects. Probably, mutable objects are not even affected by these.

Answer (score 0):

`final` means, that the value cannot be changed after initialization.

> Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object. 
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4

so unless you reassign `myObjectFinal`, **nothing bad** will happen,

However if you change the same object from multiple threads, you will need synchronization. (don't use `volatile`)

First of all, get rid of the object-orientation. An objects is a virtual construct. we are talking about low-level stuff like registers and caches - there are only primitives (every class can be reduced to a set of primitives)

The reason, why we need caches is simple.
The memory is just horrible slow. So the idea is to reduce the number of memory-accesses to a minimum.

consider the following code:

```
1. x=0;
2. if (x == 1) 
3.    x++
```

inside of your normal computer now happens something like this (without register-optimization)

```
1. write 0 into a register
   write the register into the memory
2. read x from the memory into a CPU-register
   compare it with 1 and go to 3 or 4
3. read x from the memory into a CPU-register
   increment register
   write the register into the memory
```

a lot of redundant memory operations ... but you can eliminate them

```
1. write 0 into a register
   write the register into the memory
2. compare the register with 1 and go to 3 or 4
3. increment register
   write the register into the memory
```

we keep the value of x in the register. So why not keep all variables in registers? first of all there arent that many registers available, so you cannot store everything there. Its more a temporary thing to hold a variable in a register. (inside a scope for example)
The other problem is, that no other core and/or device can read from the registers. then you need to reload/write-back the variable.

if you declare a variable as final, it will never be changed. So the variable could be stored in a register without having a problem with inconsistency. However this does not mean, that other threads cannot access the variable, since its also stored inside of the memory. Its guaranteed that the value in the memory is always valid. But all variables regardless of being final or not, can and will be stored for a short time in registers. thats why we need to use a synchronization-tool, which forces the write-back from the registers to the memory, if you want to guarantee the consistency on multiple threads/cores.

however the real CPU-cache, is a complete different topic. its a complete transparent system (executes on hardware-side!), which is only affected by the memory-access-pattern (unless you really do some crazy low-low level-stuff in assembly). To make it short here: The CPU-cache basically caches every byte, unless you explicit force it to not do it.

Comment: Since you reference the JLS already, here's the relevant reference: [JLS 17.5 final field semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5). A final field absolutely has an effect on CPU caching, it is even explicitly mentioned in the JLS that a JVM may decide to cache a final field value in a CPU register.

Comment: yes registers, but he explicit mentioned  L1-core cache, which shouldnt be affected

Comment: CPU register I think is even more unaccessible to other threads/cores than L1 when considering memory leaks. The question is about memory leaks not where exactly is cached

Comment: I don't think synchronization have anything to do to where the variable is cached. Synchronization only makes the part of the code atomic. The volatile is what tells the CPU to keep the variable accessible to all threads/cores. I don't understand why ppl. consider that volatile or synchronization are interchangeable. I don't think they are.

Comment: first, you have a problem with memory-consistency not memory-leaks. thats not the same. synchronization is to keep the consistency, that every core will see the same version of the data and every change will be executed correctly. Only in Java (not in C/C++ !) volatile works as a sychronize itself. Originall it was created to ensure, that the compiler wont optimize the code and cache the value in a register.

Comment: and synchronization does a lot more than just making something atomic. It also forces the compiler/CPU to write all changes to the memory after the synchronized-scope.

Comment: @Domo You are perfectly right. But my question is not really about how to fix this code. It is more to understand how and when the CPU caches and how the final affects that. I personally think that the mutable objects are not cached and only primitives and immutable object are cached.

Comment: What I don't understand is how/if/when/where the CPU caches a mutable object. If we are talking about primitives then everything is very simple and there is no reason to debate this. Anyway I doubt it is possible to cache an object in registers but it probably is possibele in L1

Comment: the CPU doesnt know the concept of a class. the JVM "converts" your object into an simple byte-array of primitives. These individual members are independend for the cache. this means, that the object may not be cached as a whole, but some parts are.